# Symfony 2 collection with image - editing

Tags: forms, symfony, collections

I have little problem with my collection form type.

I have relation 1 to many ( product and productImages )

I think that the problem is in my productImages Entity ( if it is possible to solve )

My productImages:

```
class produktImage
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
 */
public $file;

/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="product", inversedBy="tags")
*/
protected $product;
```

and the most importatnt method:

```
 public function upload()
    {        
        $this->name = trim(date("dmyGis").rand(1,99999999).'_'.$this->file->getClientOriginalName());
        $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->name);

        $move = new resizeImg(1280, 3000, $this->name, $this->getUploadRootDir(), null);
        $move->setThumbial(550, 2000, $this->getUploadRootDir().'../small/', null);
        $move->setThumbial(200, 2000, $this->getUploadRootDir().'../thumb/', null);

        $this->file = null;
    }
```

Form productImage has file field only.

My product entity ( the most importatnt methods )

```
    public function addPhotosum($photos)
    {
        $photos->setProdukt($this);
        $photos->upload($this);
        $this->photos->add($photos);
        return $this;
    }

    public function removePhotosum($photos)
    {
        $this->photos->removeElement($photos);
        $photos->removeImg();
    }
```

Ok, but where is my problem.
When I try to add or remove file everything is ok.
If I try to edit file nothing happen. Name and file don't change.

I think it is because Product don't see changes in name ( name is stored in db only ) but I don't know how can I tell him "change name and file when file is diffrent".
Can I use preUpdate or something else?
Someone had similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just call the upload() method in your edit action of your controller ..

example :

```
public function editAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:YourEntity')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Your entity.');
    }

    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        $entity->upload()
        $entity->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('your_destination_route', array('id' => $id)));
    }

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
    );
}
```

I hope it will work for you ..